# XCode 4.1 - Instruments Time Profiler

Tags: ios, xcode, profiling, instruments

I'm trying to use Time Profiler, I've used it before.

I'm hiding system libraries, but all of my symbol names are HEX.

I'm running in debug, I have debugSymbols turned on....

I've restarted everything a few times and cleaned everything in between..

... anybody got any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I no longer get this problem with the latest version.

Apple were no help in answering this for me - even though I used one of my Tech Support Requests. Must have had them stumped too.

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit of a pain because there are a number of variables that can cause this. some of the more common ones are:

sometimes you need to tell instruments where to find your files and/or symbols (Preferences->Search Paths).

have you enabled Link Time Optimization (LTO)? it should be off.

sometimes it helps if you do a clean/build.

sometimes it helps if you restart instruments.

in earlier versions of Xcode, it helped to use a central build directory.

verify that you are generating the proper level of debug symbols for all targets.

Comment: Thanks, done all of this and no luck. Tried with a different mac at work. No luck. Also tried with a completely different project, and a brand new project from a template - and still didn't work. Maybe someone else could try this too.... it'll only take 5 mins to create a new project > edit scheme to profile with debug > profile on their device and then Time Profiler. I've used one of my Apple tech support incidents to see if they can figure it out (i never use these)